# Change text colour on text scroll

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am using the Neve Theme on WordPress for my website development and I am customizing my header block and I am having an issue. I am using a plugin to give my header a background after 100px on scroll of the page this changes the background colour to where the text in the header is difficult to read.

The plugin offers the functionality to change the text colour but Neve overrides anything this plugin or myself can do through it. This way I am wondering if there is a way I can change the text colour through code after 100px of scroll on the website. The classes for the content are as follows

```
a.button.button-primary & .book-now-header * header.header
```

header.header is for the entire header block so that is used to change the background colour and the other 2 are for the content needing to change colour.

Any help with this would be appreciated as I am unsure where to begin.

Comment: Did you try using !important ?

Comment: Hi @talha2k Yes using !important didn't seem to have an impact even when put in the best place in my code file for it to be with that it would not change the result

Comment: Its hard to help without seeing a working copy, a link, screenshot or additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code below is detect the element scroll postition you can put the result in equation but first change number of position to hex and then use it with color you have and that will change color in your text

```js
let lastPostition = 0;
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  let x = element.scrollLeft;
  let y = element.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById ("demo").innerHTML = "Horizontally: " + x.toFixed() + "<br>Vertically: " + y.toFixed();
  console.log(lastPostition);
  if(y.toFixed() === lastPostition ){
        alert("the end of document");
  }
  lastPostition = y.toFixed()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>

<body>
<h1>The Element Object</h1>
<h2>The scrollTop and scrollLeft Properties</h2>

<p>Scroll the content below to display the number of pixels it is scrolled.</p>

<div id="myDIV" onscroll="myFunction()">
  <div id="content">Scroll me!</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
let lastPostition = 0;
function myFunction() {
  const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  let x = element.scrollLeft;
  let y = element.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById ("demo").innerHTML = "Horizontally: " + x.toFixed() + "<br>Vertically: " + y.toFixed();
  if(y.toFixed() === lastPostition ){
        alert("the end of document");
  }
  lastPostition = y.toFixed()
}
```